# How can I add a query string parameter to a link generated in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post, get

I want to send a data from an `X` view to a `Y` view, using a link.
Then, in the `Y` view, I want to display the data I send from the `X` view:

/app/views/x.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'A', y_path('data if A') %>
<%= link_to 'B', y_path('data if B') %>
```

/app/views/y.html.erb:

```
#I show the data that I receive as parameter in the link
```

What do I have to do to do this?

Comment: I think the question would be better phrased as "how can I add a query string parameter to a link generated in Ruby". Is that correct?

Comment: @ShaneStebner Yes you're right. I have just edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assign the correct value to your links:

```
# x.html.erb

<%= link_to 'A', y_path(value: 'data if A') %>
<%= link_to 'B', y_path(value: 'data if B') %>
```

Then assign the value you get from the link in the controller:

```
# y_controller.rb

def y
  @value = params[:value]
end
```

Finally, show the value using `@value` in your view:

```
# y.html.erb

<%= @value %>
```